# Compilation failed: Could not initialize class llvm.llvm

Tags: macos, kotlin, apple-m1

I'm using a MacBook M1 chip with macOS Ventura 13.0.1 and my project is KMP to build an in-house plugin used in a mobile app.

I have a custom Gradle tasks to build and publish the plugin to my local machine which used to work perfectly before I updated to Ventura but now all I get is this build error wherever the kotlin compiler reaches to linkReleaseFrameworkIos task:

```
Compilation failed: Could not initialize class llvm.llvm
```

- Source files:
- Compiler version info: Konan: 1.5.30 / Kotlin: 1.5.30
- Output kind: FRAMEWORK

I tried using different kotlin versions such as 1.6.10, 1.7.10 and 1.7.21 still the same error popped up.

Plus I gave access to Intellij to Developer Tools: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpRRb.png)

After running with stack trace:

```
Compilation failed: Could not initialize class llvm.llvm

 * Source files: 
 * Compiler version info: Konan: 1.5.30 / Kotlin: 1.5.30
 * Output kind: FRAMEWORK
```

And:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class llvm.llvm
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.BitcodePhasesKt$contextLLVMSetupPhase$1.invoke(BitcodePhases.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.BitcodePhasesKt$contextLLVMSetupPhase$1.invoke(BitcodePhases.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanLoweringPhasesKt$makeKonanModuleOpPhase$1.invoke(KonanLoweringPhases.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanLoweringPhasesKt$makeKonanModuleOpPhase$1.invoke(KonanLoweringPhases.kt:62)
```

And:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/hasanshaddad/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-aarch64-1.5.30/konan/nativelib/1650369144349498599/libllvmstubs.dylib [in thread "Execution worker for ':' Thread 4"]
```

The required .dylib does exist where it's needed but the compiler seems to be unable to load it.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWmck.png)

Any suggestions on what might cause such an issue?

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by executing the next command in the terminal, make sure to change the version in the command to your Kotlin version (Kotlin version used in the example was 1.5.30):

```
install_name_tool -change @rpath/libc++.1.dylib /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib ~/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-1.5.30/konan/nativelib/libllvmstubs.dylib
```

the folder path might contain the arch too "x86_64"

```
install_name_tool -change @rpath/libc++.1.dylib /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib ~/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-x86_64-1.5.30/konan/nativelib/libllvmstubs.dylib
```

or the arch "aarch64"

```
install_name_tool -change @rpath/libc++.1.dylib /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib ~/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-aarch64-1.5.30/konan/nativelib/libllvmstubs.dylib
```

***P.S. make sure to execute all the previous commands if you have all these folders***

Finally, execute the following command (replace the path to your app repository):

```
.../android-project-repo/gradlew --stop
```